# Inserting shortcode into php line

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to insert this sortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode('[AUTHORIMAGE-CIRCLE]');
```

and replace it with the ua1 class on this php line:

```
$STRING .= $b_f.'<a href="'.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links']['myaccount'].'" class="ua1 '.$linkclass.'">'.$CORE->_e(array('head','4')).'</a>'.$b_a;
```

This is the real code. the full one is:

```
if( $canShowBar ){ 
    if(!$isTop){ 
        $STRING .= "<div class='breadcrumb'>"; 
    } 
    if(isset($userdata) && $userdata->ID){ 
        if(isset($GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links'])){ 
            // my account 
            $STRING .= $b_f.'<a href="'.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links']['myaccount'].'" class="ua1 '.$linkclass.'">'.$CORE->_e(array('head','4')).'</a>'.$b_a;
        }
    }
}
```

when working on local host and try to modify the code, after refreshing the whole page is turning blank

Comment: And your question is? You seem to already know how to concatenate strings so what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to do so, e.g when in the line to enter the shortcode. I tried various configuration and got errors all the time

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you tried and the error code that appeared?

Comment: `$STRING .= $b_f.'<a href="'.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links']['myaccount'].'" class="'.do_shortcode('[AUTHORIMAGE-CIRCLE]').' '.$linkclass.'">'.$CORE->_e(array('head','4')).'</a>'.$b_a;`

Comment: This is some attempt i tried: $STRING .= $b_f.'<a href="'.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links']['myaccount'].echo do_shortcode('[LISTINGS show=3]');.$CORE->_e(array('head','4')).'</a>'.$b_a;
the error is when refreshing the page it won't load.

Comment: Thanks adeneo, there are no errors but for some reason the shortcode is not displaying at all... it just dissapeared the ua1 class

Comment: The error is that the page won't refresh, it just went blank

Comment: The error is not in this code!

Comment: So where the error is?

Comment: Make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code! Also please describe your error a bit more

Comment: This is the real code. the full one is:
if( $canShowBar ){
 
 if(!$isTop){ $STRING .= "<div class='breadcrumb'>"; }

   if(isset($userdata) && $userdata->ID){
    
    if(isset($GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links'])){

    // my account

    $STRING .= $b_f.'<a href="'.$GLOBALS['CORE_THEME']['links']['myaccount'].'" class="ua1 '.$linkclass.'">'.$CORE->_e(array('head','4')).'</a>'.$b_a;
         
when working on local host and try to modify the code, after refreshing the whole page is turning blank

Comment: [**Edit**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29480179/edit) your question don't post it in the comments!

Comment: I've fixed the layout of the post, also added some closing brackets as you're missing them. Also it's best practice to only use full capitals for constants.